# While loop in R repeat with error

Tags: r, matrix, matrix-inverse

I have a code like this :

```
iit = 0

while(1)
{
SIGMABf=replicate(10, rnorm(10)) 
iit=iit+1
if(inherits(solve(SIGMABf), "error")){iit=iit-1;next}
if (iit==10) {break}
}
```

However the inherits function is not working for the inverse

Is there a way to catch the error and repeat ?

Comment: I get no error with your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`try` function is here.  You can use `inherits` or more easily `class` to see if the operation failed or not.

```
a <- try(solve(1))
class(a)
# matrix
b <- try(solve(0))
class(b) 
# try-error
```

For this particular case, you may better use `det` to see if the matrix is non-sigular.  If `det(A) != 0`, then `A` is invertible.